# Multiple loops with same WP_Query in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have two loops with one same WP_Query, I tried place `wp_reset_postdata();` either right after `endwhile;` in each loop, or just once after all loops (like below), both seems to be working.

What is the correct way of doing it, and why?

```
<?php
$q = new WP_Query((array(
    'cat' => 1,
    'posts_per_page' => -1
)));

if ($q->have_posts()) :
    while ($q->have_posts()) : $q->the_post();
        // first loop
    endwhile;
endif;

if ($q->have_posts()) :
    while ($q->have_posts()) : $q->the_post();
        // second loop
    endwhile;
endif;

wp_reset_postdata(); // should reset be here or after endwhile; in each loop?
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `WP_Query::have_posts()` is called and it determines that there are no more posts, it automatically rewinds that query's result pointer to start over from the beginning. You can see the relevant code [here](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.9/src/wp-includes/class-wp-query.php#L3104), partially reproduced here:

```
} elseif ( $this->current_post + 1 == $this->post_count && $this->post_count > 0 ) {
    /* Some code removed here for the sake of brevity */

    // Do some cleaning up after the loop
    $this->rewind_posts();
}
```

From the example code [in the documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#multiple-loops), it seems that `wp_reset_postdata()` may only need to be called when you are dealing with multiple querys, but I don't know enough about WordPress to be definitive about that.